# Computation of correlation matrix

Tags: probability

In one of the papers I am reading, the following is given as the formula for computing the correlation matrix for $N$ vectors, $\{\mathbb{x_1}, \mathbb{x_2}, \cdots, \mathbb{x_N}\}$

$$ {R_X}=\frac{1}{N}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\mathbb{x_ix_i^{'}}$$

Is this formula correct? Because, if $N=2$ and each vector has $5$ elements, then the covariance  matrix and hence the correlation matrix will have dimension $2\times 2$ but according to the given formula, the dimension will be $5\times 5$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $$\mathbb{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^{5 \times 1}$$

then
$$\mathbb{x}_i\mathbb{x}_i^T \in \mathbb{R}^{5 \times 5}$$

since it is a matrix multiplication of a $5 \times 1$ and $1 \times 5$ matrix.

$N$ doesn't influence the size of the matrix.

The rank of the matrix is indeed at most $N=2$.

Comment: I do understand that. It is like adding $N$ rank-1 matrices. But  what about the dimension of the correlation matrix? Shouldn't it be $2 \times 2$ and not $5 \times 5$ even if there are 5 elements in each vector?

Comment: When the paper mention the dimension is $5 \times 5$, it is referring to the size of the matrix and not the rank. In terms of rank, the rank is at most $N$.